# Queries within queries using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to order my search results more accurately. I specify a search string - e.g. "Beijing Olympics"

- If the title column contains "Beijing Olympics" then the score 100 is added to the score, otherwise nothing is added
- If the shortDescription column contains "Beijing Olympics" then 50 is added to the score, otherwise nothing is added
- If the longDescription column contains "Beijing Olympics" then 10 is added to the score, otherwise nothing is added

In the end the maximum score possible per record would be 160 and I want the results to be ordered by highest score first and limited to a maximum of 10 results.

Below is definitely wrong, but it should illustrate what I am hoping to achieve!

```
SELECT 
    title, 
    id, 
    (
    IF((match 'Beijing Olympics' against title)*100) + 
    IF((match 'Beijing Olympics' against shortDescription)*50) + 
    IF((match 'Beijing Olympics' against longDescription)*10)
    ) as score 
from listings 
order by score desc limit 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `CASE` 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

Otherwise I think your selection logic is fine.

```
SELECT 
    title
    ,id
    ,(
        (CASE WHEN title LIKE '%Beijing Olympics%' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) 
        + (CASE WHEN shortDescription LIKE '%Beijing Olympics%' THEN 50 ELSE 0 END) 
        + (CASE WHEN longDescription LIKE '%Beijing Olympics%' THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) 
     ) AS score 
FROM 
    listings 
ORDER BY 
    score desc 
LIMIT 10
```

Note that I haven't tested this query, but it should be close.

**EDIT:** Also note that this matches for exact value.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. CASE is a new one to me!

I'm getting a MySQL error even if I try a cut down version:

SELECT title ,id, (CASE title WHEN 'Beijing Olympics' THEN 100 ELSE 0) as score FROM listings 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as score FROM listings

Comment: Ah ha, looks like I need to add END

Comment: Strange - if I use END CASE at the end of each line I get an error, if I just use END then the query completes successfully. How do I tweak your beautiful example so it checks to see if the columns contain (i.e. LIKE) "Beijing Olympics" rather than being equal to "Beijing Olympics". I appreciate your help!

Comment: Just replace the equality with the `LIKE` I've edited the answer again :D

Comment: You genius! It works - I just needed to add a LIKE after longDescription on the third line